Need an isolated controllable resistance of about 10 to 20K ohm
I need something like a vactrol (led + photocell) which can create a controlled, (opto-)isolated variable resistance of 10-20K ohm.  Problem with vactrols is that their dark resistance is > 500K ohm which means in order to get in the range I need will require the vactrol led to be "on" all the time.  Are their other options than a vactrol that meet my requirements?, preferably with a 15K ohm resistance when the device is unpowered. I have considered a 0-10K digital potentiometer with 10K resistor but unsure if the resistance generated will be isolated from the control voltages and too not sure if one can set/buy a default(unpowered) resistance for a digipot (see use case below).
Use Case:
In order to create a 21st century home automation thermostat to the antiquated controller in a popular oil stove, toyostove laser73, without busting into stove all I need to do is replace the 10K ohm thermistor with a variable resistor I can control.  For example if I set the stove's setpoint to 60 degrees F that is about 15Kohm for a 10K thermistor
(10K thermistor table), then if I cut off the external/factory 10K thermistor and replace it with a resistance I can control I can turn the heating on and off by simply raising or lowering the resistance from 15K.....bob's your uncle! I can now create a smart home automation thermostat for this stove without even taking a screwdriver to it.
Just to confirm I replaced the thermistor with a multiturn trim pot and it works as  expected.  As I increase or decrease the trim pot from 15K it goes down and up from 60F. So it dawned on me, one really funky way to get a controllable, isolated resistance would be to put a tiny stepper motor on the wiper of the trim pot to turn it.  But hey it's the 21st century isn't there a better way (could a digital pot work)?

Just put a resistor in parallel with a photoresistor. The parallel resistance sets the maximum resistance with cell in dark. That said, be sure that the mods to the stove do not create a potential safety hazard. Would circuit failure, either in ON or OFF state, be a fire hazard?

Ah duh yes a parallel resistor.   As to safety I wanted the unpowered (OFF) state to be such that the resistance the stove sees is higher (lower temp) than the "fake" setpoint.   You got me thinking about a failed ON state.  I could put in a relay at the plug if my thermostat senses a "run away" condition (room temp >>> room setpoint) it can just shut the whole stove off.

Not sure why someone voted this down :(.  Sure would like to know why.  I thought  my question was clear with enough details which is born out by two very useful answers. Thx to them.

You could use a mechanical relay or opto-MOS SSR to switch a resistor in  parallel with the existing sensor. Here is an example of a normally-closed opto-MOS relay, so passing current through the LED will cause the 'contact' to open.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
So you set the thermostat to the maximum temperature you would ever want, say in this case it's 8.2kΩ for about 30°C (85°F). When the contact is open the device will cycle to maintain that temperature. Close the contact and it will switch at about 16°C (60°F).
In between those temperatures your controller can cycle the heat on and off by faking out the reading.
That makes certain assumptions about how the controller in the box works, and assumes it has the appropriate safety and timing devices to ignite and shut down properly. That's up to you to verify to ensure safe operation as there is no way we can evaluate the risks.

That should work! Thx.  But why not use a fixed resistance for thermistor and put the setpoint just below that (safety wise so it's off if relay not energized).    If I want more "fine" control and could could double or triple down on that relay with different resistances kinda like a digi pot.

I'm marking this as the answer but one by Dr. Moshie in question comment is also a good answer.

The reason to retain the thermistor is to put guard rails on the authority of your controller. It cannot cause the temperature to go higher than the maximum or lower than the minimum even if the program crashes or it fails (for most plausible kinds of failures anyway).  It's already there, why not keep it when it provides a valuable service?

In the data sheet I don't see a voltage range for the "coil".   But it says On-Resistance max 10 ohm (neglible), LED Current to Operate .16-0.5 mA.  So controlling via esp gpio @ 3.3V (gpio effectively no resistance) if I put a 15K resistor in series should be about .22mA.   That sound right?

I would use 1kΩ for more like 2mA nominal. That puts it in the middle of the characteristic curves.

for those looking to buy that mosfet here is link at aliexpress.  https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256806426538861.html  Looks like the CPC1117N will also work (NC).  https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/240/media-3322407.pdf
